# How to convert turn-by-turn text directions into polyline data

Tags: line, route, map-service

I am interested in converting **turn-by-turn text directions** into **polyline data**.

For example, the turn-by-turn text directions would look like this:

```
STARTING AT 1805 VICTORIA DR - SOUTH ON VICTORIA DR TO E 5TH STR - EAST ON 5TH E STR TO TEMPLETON DR - NORTH ON TEMPLETON DR TO 1938 TEMPLETON DR
```

As an output, I would like a **polyline** representing the route travelled.

Everything I have come across while researching this problem is the opposite of what I want to accomplish, i.e. converting a route or start/end coordinates into turn-by-turn directions.

Solution I have considered:

1. Parse the input string by turns, i.e. parse by the dash
2. For each turn, parse further by 'TO', i.e. "SOUTH ON VICTORIA DR" 'TO' "E 5TH STR"
3. Geocode each turn segment and/or create point coordinate for each turn segment
4. Convert point to line = Route

But, issues arise when geocoding only a direction and street; i.e. what does **SOUTH ON VICTORIA DR**  mean in terms of a point? Is this possible?

Has anyone thought of this before or heard of something along these lines? Any insight would be much appreciated.

PS. I am not opposed to utilizing LLM if that is an option as well.

Comment: It's a hard problem (or was 15 years ago when the DHS funded a project to look at it) - see for example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221607254_Automatic_Extraction_of_Destinations_Origins_and_Route_Parts_from_Human_Generated_Route_Directions